# SSRS maintaining space between report objects

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have written a report in SSRS 2008 R2 but when displayed in the browser there is extra whitespace being left in the middle of the report, despite trying various different combinations of rectangles.

A simplified sketch of the report layout is shown in the following link (sorry I don't have enough posts to embed images):

[Report Layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s4umaRqwTbR0ZQOW1pWWc2b1k/edit?usp=sharing)

The problem is that when the number of rows in Table B cause it to expand downward Table D is also pushed downwards leaving a gap between them:

[Layout with extra whitespace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s4umaRqwTbYTJBSHRGSlM4QXM/edit?usp=sharing)

I believe this is because SSRS assumes that I want to maintain the spacing between Table B and Table D.

Table A and Gauge C are already in a rectangle to prevent the position of the gauge being affected by Table B.  I have also tried the following:

- No other rectangles
- An additional rectangle containing only Table B
- A full width rectangle containing both Table B and the Table A/Gauge C rectangle
- A rectangle round Table D
- Combinations of the above

In every case the space between Tables B and D is maintained when Table B grows.

Does anyone have any suggestions for preventing this whitespace being maintained?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem and no luck finding answers :-/